# Calls from my iPhone to friend's iPhone always go to voicemail, and he never gets my texts anymore

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, text, call

**EDIT: For others with the same problem: Phong was right, my friend had actually inadvertently blocked me.**

I have an iPhone 6s and my friend has maybe the 6 or 5, but definitely an iPhone as well.

We used to receive each other's calls and texts no problem. Starting about a week ago though, he stopped receiving any of my texts but I still get all of his.

Also, any time I call him my calls go directly to his voicemail without ringing (and we tried enough times to make sure that his phone was on and should've rung) but he can call me just fine and my phone will ring.

I'm not having this problem with anyone else as far as I can tell (my gf and other friends get my texts and I can call other numbers).

One thing is that when I text this friend, I never see "Delivered" under the text.

Comment: your friend has probably blocked your number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your friend may have blocked you accidentally. Have him open your contact card, and scroll to the bottom. If he did in fact block you, he will see a button to `Unblock this caller`.

Blocking requires no confirmation, and that button is present at the bottom of every contact card, so it’s easy to tap on accident.

Comment: Thanks. I actually thought about that possibility and discarded it thinking it was too unlikely; but if you say it requires no confirmation that makes it more likely, I'll ask him to check.

Comment: If he’s blocked your number and you leave him a voicemail, your voicemail will go into a dedicated mailbox labeled **Blocked Messages**. It will be located at the very bottom of his list of voicemails, beneath **Deleted Messages**.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know (and for others with the same problem I'll edit my OP); you were right, he had blocked my number inadvertently. I can't believe I actually thought about it this morning and discarded the possibility. There's a lesson for me in there somewhere...